# How to order by the field stored in the separate model?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here is simplified version of my datastore structure:

```
class News(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()

class NewsRating(db.Model):
    user = db.IntegerProperty()
    rating = db.IntegerProperty()
    news = db.ReferenceProperty(News)
```

Now I need to display all news sorted by their total rating (sum of different users ratings). How can I do that in the following code:

```
news = News.all()
# filter by additional parms
# news.filter("city =", "1")
news.order("-added") # ?
for one_news in news:
    self.response.out.write(one_news.title()+'<br>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Queries only have access to the entity you're querying against, if you have a property from another entity (or some aggregate calculation based on fields from other entities) that you want to use to order results, you're going to need to store it in the entity you're querying against.

In the case of ratings, that might mean a periodic task that sums up ratings and distributes them to articles.

Comment: So, I should add new property Rating to each News entity, right? If I wish to update it each time when new record to NewsRating is added, how can I make sure that each vote is counted (i.e. there is no write transaction when I read and write another transaction)?

Comment: Dave, looks like there is no much sence in my scenario to user Sharding counters (I don't expect to have more than 5 votes per second per each news). So, I can follow the approach described in my comment above. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

To do that you would need to run a query fetching every single `NewsRating` referencing your `News` entity and sum all the ratings (as the datastore does not provide JOINs). This will be a huge task both time and cost wise. I'd recommend to take a look at [just-overheard-it](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/overheard) example as a reference point.