# How to handle counter updates in the GAE datastore properly?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, counter

Let's say I have page views counter in my datastore.
In order to increase its value with each page display, I need to read the value, increment that and increase. How can I be sure that in case when 2 (or more) users view the page, both views are counted (i.e. there will not be a case that for user2 we read the counter value before we've updated that for user1)?

Comment: Sorry, I've taken page-views just as simplified example and looks like that wasn't correct - the details are provided in the separate question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784808/how-to-order-by-the-field-stored-in-the-separate-model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to sharded counters where exact values are less important than performance, consider using [write-behind counters](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding). Alternately, use something like Google Analytics, rather than trying to count pageviews yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use [Sharded Counters](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) for such cases.